# You have requested a non-existent service "security.access.decision_manager"

Tags: php, symfony, security

I am trying to build a project without using security (no login and register form in my project). When I remove `- { resource: security.yml }` on my `config.yml`, I get this error.

`You have requested a non-existent service "security.access.decision_manager"`

I have tried to search for using Symfony without security, but there is none.

Is there anything that I missing?

Comment: Have you tried cache clear?

Comment: Yes, I did. But, it didn't work.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible, what is your use case for needing to disable the security system?

Comment: my project will be only about displaying content. no login and register needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* just disable it. Comment/ remove file works fine on symfony standard edition without throwing errors. If it does not, you are most likely using some component of it (or even in a service you are using).

Also just commenting it out does not disable it - it would just load the default config settings as defined in the bundle. To remove it from loading:

```
// remove/ comment in AppKernel.php
$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle();
```

---

Also another option you might want to consider is starting off with the [MicroKernelTrait](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/micro_kernel_trait.html) and extend that with what you need instead of getting everything and trying to remove bits.

Comment: oh, this is nice. Thanks for pointing it out. Although I have to remove JMS Security besides the one you mentioned.